# How do you validate the PropTypes of a nested object in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a data object as my props for a component in ReactJS.

```
<Field data={data} />
```

I know its easy to validate the PropTypes object itself:

```
propTypes: {
  data: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

But what if I want to validate the values inside?  ie.  data.id, data.title?

```
props[propName]: React.PropTypes.number.required // etc...
```

Answer (score 409, accepted):

You can use `React.PropTypes.shape` to validate properties:

```
propTypes: {
    data: React.PropTypes.shape({
      id: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      title: React.PropTypes.string
    })
}
```

**Update**

As @Chris pointed out in comments, as of React version 15.5.0 `React.PropTypes` has moved to package `prop-types`.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';    

propTypes: {
    data: PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      title: PropTypes.string
    })
}
```

[More info](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-react.proptypes)

Comment: Precise answer @nilgun. You can find documentation for React's propTypes: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

Comment: `React.PropTypes` is now deprecated. Please use `PropTypes` from the `prop-types` package instead. [More here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-react.proptypes)

Answer (score 16):

Wanted to note that nesting works beyond one level deep. This was useful for me when validating URL params:

```
propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
  })
};
```

Comment: Does that mean the `id` is only required if there is a `match.params` object or does the `isRequired` cascade, meaning `match` isRequired with a `params` object with an `id` prop? ie, if no params were provided would it still be valid?

Comment: This can be read as "`match` needs to have `params` and `params` needs to have `id`".

Comment: Hi @datchung actually I since found out (and tested) how it reads and it is that If `match` is present and If `match` contains `params` then it is required `params` contains a string `id`.

Answer (score 14):

If `React.PropTypes.shape` doesn't give you the level of type checking you want, have a look at [tcomb-react](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-react).

It provides a [`toPropTypes()`](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-react/blob/master/propTypes.js) function which lets you validate a schema defined with the [tcomb](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb) library by making use of React's support for defining [custom `propTypes` validators](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html), running validations using [tcomb-validation](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-validation).

[Basic example from its docs](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-validation#an-alternative-syntax-for-react-proptypes):

```
// define the component props
var MyProps = struct({
  foo: Num,
  bar: subtype(Str, function (s) { return s.length <= 3; }, 'Bar')
});

// a simple component
var MyComponent = React.createClass({

  propTypes: toPropTypes(MyProps), // <--- !

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Foo is: {this.props.foo}</div>
        <div>Bar is: {this.props.bar}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }    
});
```

Answer (score -6):

```
user: React.PropTypes.shap({
    age: (props, propName) => {
       if (!props[propName] > 0 && props[propName] > 100) {
          return new Error(`${propName} must be betwen 1 and 99`)
       }
       return null
    },
})
```

Comment: As much effort obviously has gone into this answer, it might be difficult to get a grasp at if it's just code. It's usual to comment the solution with a few sentences. Please edit your answer and add some explanation.