# How to specify the shape of a map with numeric keys using React.PropTypes?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a simple way of defining the shape of the following map as a prop to a react component?

```
users: {
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Andrew'
  },
  55: {              // arbitrary number of these entries all keyed by ID
    id: 55,
    name: 'Barry'
  }
}
```

How can I declare that `users` should contain numeric keys with values of the shape `{id: number, name: string}`?

Comment: @MattStyles Not true, you can use `shape` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923042/how-do-you-validate-the-proptypes-of-a-nested-object-in-reactjs

Comment: You might want to consider turning `users` into an array though. Would probably be easier to work with

Comment: @azium I've currently implemented it as an array but I'd shave nano seconds off and save some typing by having it as a map where I can look up entries by ID. As it is I have O(n) complexity for lookups because I have to go through all items comparing `id`s.

Comment: I just flagged as a duplicate. Look at the linked question (asked by me ironically enough). There is enough in there for you to get it. You can swap out `arrayOf` with `mapOf`

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Thanks. I wish this was easier and documented in the react docs.

Comment: @azium live and learn! Thanks for the correction, I'll delete my comment!