# How to validate the class of a Prop and class of it's field (nested object) in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a class like this:

```
class ResponseState() {
   constructor(data) {
      this.data = data;
   }
}
```

Now I can validate that the prop is of this type:

```
Container.propTypes = {
   myProp: PropTypes.instanceOf(ResponseState).isRequired,
};
```

This works fine, but how can I validate the type of `myProp.data` as well? If I use `PropTypes.shape`, then I cannot check `myProp` itself.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923042/how-do-you-validate-the-proptypes-of-a-nested-object-in-reactjs), but it does not quite give the answer to this exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised not to see any combining forms for [`PropTypes`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

You could use a custom validator:

```
Container.propTypes = {
   myProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
      if (!propName in props) {
         return new Error(propName + " is required");
      }
      const value = props[propName];
      if (!(value instanceof ResponseState)) {
         return new Error(propName + " must be an instance of ResponseState");
      }
      if (/*...validate value.data here ...*/) {
         return new Error(propName + " must have etc. etc.");
      }
   }
};
```

Comment: Seems rather heavy weight, taking into account I'll have to do it in few places, and data is different class for various containers... But thanks for the answer, seems there is no better way of doing it.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: Yeah. If you delve into the React source a bit you could probably reuse `PropTypes.instanceOf` and `shape` in the validator, but... FYI, ran across [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1836#issuecomment-68741246) on a ReactJS issue: *"Proptypes are being phased out in favor of tools like Flow."*