# React undefined props issue

Tags: reactjs

I'm passing a props object to a child component. The problem I'm having is that sometimes some of the nested values will be null, or undefined, and therefore I'm getting the dreaded props undefined message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined`.

As I understand `defaultProps` is only triggered when the props object is null, not when only *some* of its values are null.

Example:

```
this.state {
    person: { 
        name: "Matt", 
        age: 34, 
        OtherDetails: { city:"", country: "" } 
    }
}
```

In the example above sometimes the city or country values will be null or undefined. Checking for these instances seems very difficult and laborious - what is the best way to deal with situations like this when props data is partial and unreliable?

Comment: Are you using Redux?

Comment: Have you looked into trying PropTypes ?

Comment: Yes redux and PropTypes only triggers is defaultProps does, doesn't it?

Comment: Also, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26924696/4759033

Comment: *"Checking for these instances seems very difficult and laborious"* Not at all, actually. The ideal solution is to always send the whole object. If your component requires all properties on an object, then the parent component should send them. However, it's not so difficult to check every object before using, e.g. `const otherDetails = this.state.person.otherDetails || {}` or use an API that can handle nulls correctly, e.g. `_.get` in `lodash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If as your question suggests you are just trying to pass an object as a prop, and then access properties of that object in your component that may not exist then have you considered providing default values? (This assumes your using ES6 syntax).

I would use destructuring in the render method to access each property I am going to use in the render method, and for each item provide a default value as below.

```
class PersonComp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {
            name = '',
            age = 0,
            OtherDetails: {city = ''},
            OtherDetails: {country = ''}

        } = this.props.person;

        return (
            <div>
                <div>{name}</div>
                <div>{age}</div> 
                <div>{city}</div>
                <div>{country}</div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

By doing this should city or country not exist in the data provided then they will be created and assigned the value of empty string.

Comment: This did the trick however, I had to assign city = "" on its own row (not as a key within the OtherDetails object)