# React: Prop type must be a function, but received object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm confused by this error message, and have reached a dead end googling. Please let me know if you have insight!

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Results: prop type `leoInfo` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `object`.
```

Template:

```
const StateTool = ({ state, leoInfo }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {/* other stuff */}
      <LEOLink leoInfo={leoInfo} state={state} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Props:

```
StateTool.propTypes = {
  state: PropTypes.string,
  leoInfo: {
    regionId: PropTypes.string, 
    phoneNumbers: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
  },
};
```

Comment: Hi There !!! React.PropTypes.shape() required not the direct {} :)

Comment: Do vote and accept  answer if your task is resolved. :) Happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object prop types must be declared using [`PropTypes.shape(...)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes):

```
StateTool.propTypes = {
  state: PropTypes.string,
  leoInfo: PropTypes.shape({
    regionId: PropTypes.string, 
    phoneNumbers: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
  }),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This question already has the answer here.

[How do you validate the PropTypes of a nested object in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923042/how-do-you-validate-the-proptypes-of-a-nested-object-in-reactjs)

So your basically need `React.PropTypes.shape({})`

Comment: Thank you for the link!

Comment: It's my pleasure :)